# TreeView with Checkboxes (populate dynamically)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using MVC 5.

I want to create a TreeView with checkboxes. The TreeView should get populated from database dynamically.

Selecting a child node should automatically select parent node.

Any MVC library available to do so without using jQuery?

I tried few jQuery samples but there is an issue. Selecting a child node is not selecting parent node.

Comment: With your reputation score, you should know by now this kind of question isn't suited for SO...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my suggestion for you is to use fancytree. because this component has stronger structure than jstree:
[Checkbox Sample](http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/index.html#sample-select.html)

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: jstree is a jquery plugin. And checkboxes are enabled as a plugin for jstree

I respond just because probably someone will look for this again.

https://www.jstree.com/ does the trick. There are tri-state checkboxes (checked, unchecked, partially checked if there is a children or nephew or ... unchecked)

You must include the checkbox plugin which is used to render a checkbox in front of each row.

```
$(function () {
  $("#plugins1").jstree({
    "checkbox" : {
      "keep_selected_style" : false
    },
    "plugins" : [ "checkbox" ]
  });
});
```

And as they said there is an important feature described in documentation as:

> Undetermined state is automatically calculated, but if you are using
>   AJAX and loading on demand and want to render a node as underemined
>   pass "undetermined" : true in its state.

And here is a asp.net mvc wrapper for that: https://jstreemvcwrapper.codeplex.com/